# convertir consulta sql en linq para c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq

amigos buen día, solicito su ayuda para poder convertir la siguiente consulta a linq.

```
SELECT a.MtoFalloId, c.MtoProveedorId, g.RazonSocial, d.NoContrato, a.MtoRequerimientoId, a.PorcetajeAsignado
FROM     dbo.MtoFallo AS a INNER JOIN
                  dbo.MtoProcedimiento AS b ON a.MtoProcedimientoId = b.MtoProcedimientoId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.MtoOferta AS c ON a.MtoOfertaId = c.MtoOfertaId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.MtoContrato AS d ON b.MtoProcedimientoId = d.MtoProcedimientoId AND c.MtoProveedorId = d.MtoProveedorId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.DetalleContrato AS f ON d.MtoContratoId = f.MtoContratoId AND a.MtoRequerimientoId = f.MtoRequerimientoId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.MtoProveedor AS g ON c.MtoProveedorId = g.MtoProveedorId AND d.MtoProveedorId = g.MtoProveedorId
WHERE  (a.MtoRequerimientoId = 5604)
```

estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
 var ListaOfertas = from f in db.MtoFallo
                           join p in db.MtoProcedimientos on f.MtoProcedimientoId equals p.MtoProcedimientoId
                           join mo in db.MtoOfertas on f.MtoOfertaId equals mo.MtoOfertaId
                           join mc in db.MtoContratos on p.MtoProcedimientoId equals mc.MtoProcedimientoId && mo.MtoProveedorId == mc.MtoProveedorId
                           join dc in db. DetalleContratos on mc.MtocontratoId equals dc.MtoContratoId && f.MtoRequerimientoId == dc.MtoRequerimientoId
                           join mp in db. MtoProveedores on mo.MtoProveedorId equals mp.MtoProveedorId
                            select new 
                            {
                                MtoFalloId= f.MtoFalloId,
                            };
```

sin embargo me manda el siguiente mensaje

el nombre mo no esta dentro del anbito del lado derecho de equals puede cambiar las expresiones en cualquier lado de equals

el nombre f no esta dentro del anbito del lado derecho de equals puede cambiar las expresiones en cualquier lado de equals

podrian echarme una mano por favor muchas gracias

Comment: Una solución rápida sería que crees una vista en SQL y ya la llamas desde de C# con un select simple con LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar un `join` en `linq` por mas de una key no se usa el `&&` deberias aplicar

[Join by using composite keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys)

```
join mc in db.MtoContratos on new { p.MtoProcedimientoId, mo.MtoProveedorId } equals new { mc.MtoProcedimientoId, mc.MtoProveedorId }
```

se usa el `new` para crear un objeto nuevo que defina las propiedades que se igualan

Igualmente esta raro que incluyas a `mo` y `p` para comparalo con campos de `mc` se supone que cuando igualas deben ser campos de las mismas tablas involucradas.

Tambien aplica a

```
join dc in db.DetalleContratos on new { mc.MtocontratoId, f.MtoRequerimientoId } equals  new { dc.MtoContratoId, dc.MtoRequerimientoId }
```

aqui nuevamente cruzas los campos de otras tablas al usar `mc` y `f` con campos de `dc`, eso revisalo porque esta raro. Se supone que si igualas sean campos de `mc` o de `f` pero de uno de estos no ambos.

Comment: que tal amigo leandro no entendi muy bien tu ultimo comentario, podrias explicarme un poco mejor.

Comment: lo que menciono revises es que tanto en sql o linq cuando unes dos tablas o entidades relacionas propiedades solo de estas dos y no pones una tercera en medio, eso es justo lo que haces. Si relacionas `mc` con `dc` usa una o mas propiedades solo de estas dos, poner en medio `f` no es correcto